# Is it worthwhile to setup HTTP 2 reverse proxy in front of HTTP 1 server?

Tags: reverse-proxy, http2

Say I setup Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of IIS and enable HTTP/2 support on Nginx for browsers.

Would I see any benefits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the scenarios Nginx explicitely supports, and you would most likely see at least some performance gains due to the improved pipelining, having only a single TLS session to negotiate, etc... assuming your application's architecture is such that it would profit from those benefits.

However, beware that some of the oft-used HTTP 1.1 hacks you may have implemented to optimize your  performance in the past (e.g. domain sharding, image sprites...) are actually counter-productive with HTTP2, so you may want to tweak your config such that they are only used for HTTP1.1 clients.

These points are addressed in greater detail here : https://www.nginx.com/blog/7-tips-for-faster-http2-performance/